# how will i disable textbox and enable button when the textbox is equal to true

Tags: jquery

I have two textboxes where if  `valuetags` is `true` the `quantitytotransfer` should be disabled but its not happening with this series of codes any help ?

```
        $(function () {
                $('#valuetags').value(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
                        $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
            });
<input name="valuetags" type="text" class="form-control"  id="valuetags"> 
                                        <input type="number"  required class="form-control" name="quantitytotransfer" id="quantitytotransfer" maxlength="11" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" >

<button class="btn btn-success btn-flat"  disabled id="submit" >Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Please show your isNumber function too. And what's this event "va" supposed to mean??

Comment: the isNumber is nothing to do with the function va suppoed to be value

Comment: Well, there's no event called "value". I guess this is where you're getting it wrong. Please clarify something. You want the quality to transfer to be disabled when we write something in valuetags input box. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$('#valuetags').value(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
                    $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            });
```

With

```
$('#valuetags').on("keyup", function(){
   if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
      $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', true);
   } else {
      $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', false);
   }
 });
```

Comment: $(function() {
         $('#valuetags').val($("#tags option").length==0)
});

Comment: idid not type the true value its tre result of the code above

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that "value" isn't an event. You can use keyup event here.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#valuetags').on("keyup", function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
       $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
       $('#quantitytotransfer').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

You may want to refer to this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fz7w1zk5/

Comment: $(function() { $('#valuetags').val($("#tags option").length==0) });

Comment: idid not type the true value its the result of the code above